# how to make a transparent image in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make the A image transparently when the mouse pointer is over the B image
so that I can see either image.

How should I change this?

[image]

Comment: I don't know how I can edit my question.  A image is images/modal1-1.jpg (mouseover image) , and B image is images/modal1.jpg(mouseout image).

Comment: Can you add some relevant markup?

Comment: you can do it using css rite ? why jquery any specific requirement ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having trouble with posting code here, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you include this with any jQuery code you use:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This demo is simplified to show some possibilities.

- jQuery has a number of [mouse events](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/) (see image B)
- Using [`.css()`](https://api.jquery.com/css/), you can change properties like:

  - [`display`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)
  - [`visibility`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp) (see image A)
  - [`opacity`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp)
- You can use the jQuery methods [`hide()`](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [`show()`](https://api.jquery.com/show/) (see image C)
- Or try assigning a class to the targeted element with a property mentioned previously, then use [`addClass`](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [`removeClass`](https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) (see image D)

**Snippet**

```js
$(function() {
  $('.B').mouseover(function() {
    $('.A').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $('.C').hide();
    $('.D').addClass('invisible');
  });
  $('.B').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.A').css('visibility', 'visible');
    $('.C').show();
    $('.D').removeClass('invisible');
  });
});
```

```css
.invisible {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/000/fff?text=A" class="A">
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/00e/fc1?text=B" class="B">
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/fc1/00e?text=C" class="C">
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/e0e/fcf?text=D" class="D">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS opacity property to make image transparent

```
$("img").bind("mouseover", function() {
  $("img").css("opacity", "0.5");
  $(this).css("opacity", "1");
});
```

Here is link to JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8hbmyu9k/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can change the [opacity value](http://www.corelangs.com/css/box/transparent.html) of image on the hover event of image B.

```
img.transparent
{
   opacity: 0.3; filter: alpha(opacity=30); /* For IE 8 & 9 (more valid) */
}
```

Now at the hover event of image B (img tag with class B)

```
$("img.B").hover(function(){
   $("img.A").addClass("transparent");    
},function(){
   $("img.A").removeClass("transparent");    
});
```